# Tcl Class - go to default method if method is not defined?

Tags: class, methods, tcl

Is it passable? if method is not defined and not inherited, I need to go to a default method instead of returning an error.

tnx

Comment: What kind of class? Tcl has a few extension to implement class such as iTcl.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Tcl 8.6's built in `oo::class` here, that routes all failures to resolve a method to the built-in `unknown` method of the object you're calling it on, including where no method name is given at all. The default implementation (in the `oo::object` class, not exported to the public class API by default) just prints out an appropriate error message, but you can do anything you want:

```
oo::class create MyExample {
    method unknown {args} {
        if {[llength $args] == 0} {
            tailcall my NoArguments
        }
        # Fall through to default processing otherwise
        next {*}$args
    }
    method NoArguments {} {
        puts "Called with no arguments"
    }
}
```

That lets me do this (segment of) session in Tcl 8.6.3:

```
% MyExample create eg
::eg
% eg abc
unknown method "abc": must be destroy or unknown
% eg
Called with no arguments
% eg destroy
% eg
invalid command name "eg"
```